# search fro duplicate values and remove from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Ok so I have the following:

```
var alldatesdump = booking.getalldates();

var alldatesdumparray = $.map(booking.getalldates(), function(value, index) {
    var splitstring
    var dropdates = new Date(value.date);
    var dropdate = dropdates.getDate();
    var month=new Array();
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";
    var dropmonth = month[dropdates.getMonth()];
    var dropyear = dropdates.getFullYear();
console.log(dropmonth + "-" + dropyear);

    return [value];
});
```

which outputs the following:

```
October-2014 
October-2014 
October-2014 
November-2014 
November-2014 
November-2014
```

how do i stop it from repeating values and just out put once per month.... 
Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Finding Distinct Values in Object Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431618/jquery-finding-distinct-values-in-object-array)

Comment: thank you i search high and low and just did not come up with that answer!